# take background default in IE when i use of PIE.htc

Tags: jquery, css, css3pie

I am using PIE.htc file in my project to support css3 property like border-radius and box-shadow in IE.

But my issue is that when i add PIE.htc file then IE8 take automatically background color:#686C5A.I use this color as box-shadow color.But it take whole area of div#main.Not as box-shadow.

```
#main{
    width: 1005px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 #686C5A;
    behavior: url('PIE.htc');
}
```

This color spread over to div#main.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused; I see `686C5A` in your stylesheet.  Is the problem that it's not that color?

Comment: I edit my question.Please see it and help me to get out of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add background color for main div.... you didn't mention background color for main DIV... because of that IE box shadow behaving like that... hope this will work for you..

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, see: https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/12

You will have to either give your element an opaque background, or do without box-shadow in IE.